# android: Displaying multiple images like INSIDE the Tinder-cards

Tags: android, image-gallery, tinder

How would I go about displaying multiple images the way Tinder does it: it should display the next image when I click on the right side of the image and display the previous image when I click on the left side of the image.

[image]

It should also display a little arrow to the right or left only when clicked and show somehow which picture is being displayed (with little bars like tinder or dots or something).

Is there a library for that?

**EDIT:**
To clarify: I already implemented the Tinder swipe-cards with the help of the [Diolor/Swipecards](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) library. What I'm suprisingly a little stuck with is implementing the **image gallery INSIDE the Tinder swipecards**. Only the part seen in the picture above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was adding two pictures of arrows, putting two layouts above them, then adding onClickListeners for the Layouts, which select the next/previous picture in the adapter to be displayed in the ImageView.

The layout .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="100sp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewMainBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_user_default" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/outline_keyboard_arrow_right_black_48" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePrevious"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/outline_keyboard_arrow_left_black_48" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/previousLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/nextLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:shadowRadius="20"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                tools:text="hello" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/infoImageViewItemCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:shadowRadius="20"
                android:src="@drawable/outline_info_white_48" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of libraries to it for you

https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView

https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

https://github.com/Ivaskuu/tinder_cards

https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda-Android

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, please have a look at the edit of my question.

Comment: Hey..did you figure it out?